# Sending additional field data with uploadify

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, uploadify

I want to send an additional field with uploadify, I cant get the field value on backend php file with following code. Can someone see if my HTML, and js code is correct?
Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fileUpload").fileUpload({
        'uploader': 'uploadify/uploader.swf',
        'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
        'script': 'uploadify/upload.php',
        'folder': 'files',
        'multi': false,
        'displayData': 'speed',
        'scriptData': {'name':'', 'location':''},
        'onSelectOnce' : function(event,data) {
            $("#fileUpload").uploadifySettings('scriptData', {'name' : $('#name').val()});
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<h2>Single File Upload</h2>
        <p>Display speed</p>
         Name: <input name="name" id="name" type="text" maxlength="255" size="50" />
        <div id="fileUpload">You have a problem with your javascript</div>
        <a href="javascript:$('#fileUpload').fileUploadStart()">Start Upload</a> |  <a href="javascript:$('#fileUpload').fileUploadClearQueue()">Clear Queue</a>
```

upload.php

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
```

Comment: Have you debugged the `onSelectOnce()` call? Are you 100% sure the values are actually being set? (Test output e.g. using `alert()` or `console.log()`)

Comment: Doesn't it send those params via POST?

Comment: @Jaitsu: Can you give any example please?

Comment: try changing to `$name = $_POST['name'];` and see if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
'scriptData': {'name':$("#name").val()},
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#fileUpload").fileUpload({
    'uploader': 'uploadify/uploader.swf',
    'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
    'script': 'uploadify/upload.php',
    'folder': 'files',
    'multi': false,
    'displayData': 'speed',
    'scriptData': {'name':'name':$("#name").val(), 'location':''},
    'onSelectOnce' : function(event,data) {
        $("#fileUpload").uploadifySettings('scriptData', {'name' : $('#name').val()});
    }
});
```

});